# SQL Server Full-Text Search Order by another Column Performance

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, optimization, index-tuning, full-text-search

I have two tables, `Entity` and `EntityDetails`.

`Entity` table has columns `EntityId`, `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`, `LastUpdated (smalldatetime)`.

`EntityDetails` table has columns `EntityId`, `Details1`, `Details2`.

Where `Col3` in `Entity` table and `Details1` and `Details2` in `EntiryDetails` table are full text indexed.

I also have a `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` on `Entity` table.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LastUpdated] ON [dbo].[Entity]
(
    [LastUpdated] DESC,
    [Col2] ASC
)
INCLUDE(EntityId, Col1, Col3) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Now, when I perform full text search on full text indexed columns using `CONTAINS(EntityDetails.[Details1],EntityDetails.[Details2],EntityDetails.[Details3,@Keywords])`, everything works fine if the results are served as it is. But when I add `Order By LastUpdated` to the query I see 'Worktable' with a lot of `Scans` and thousands of `logical reads` in query `statistics` and `Index Spool (Eager)`.

I thought its probably because the results returned by the fulltext search are in default order of the `key` column.

So I added a `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` on `EntityDetails`.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_EntityDetails] ON [dbo].[EntityDetails]
(
    [EntityId] DESC
)
INCLUDE([Details1],[Details2],[Details3]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And tried `ORDER BY EntityId DESC`, but still same.

Can anyone please help?

**Update**

Here's the query plan
[image: Query Plan Full text Search Enger Spool]

**URL to Query Plan**

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyF0nB_9U

**Full Text Indexes**

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON EntityDetails(Details1,Details2,Details3) KEY INDEX PK_EntityDetails;

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Entity(Col3) KEY INDEX PK_Entity;
```

**NONCLUSTERED Index on Entity Table**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_EntityLastUpdated] ON [dbo].[Entity]
(
    [LastUpdated] DESC,
    [Col4] ASC,
    [Col5] ASC,
    [Col6] ASC
)
INCLUDE([EntityId],[Col1],[Col2],[Col3]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Update 2**

Here's the updated plan with `INDEX(PK_Entity)` and `ORDER BY EntityId DESC`

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SknlXxj9I

and with `INDEX(PK_Entity)` and `ORDER BY LastUpdated DESC`

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkjV7gs98

**Update 3**

After trying the Answer:

When using

```
DECLARE @Keywords varchar(255) = 'keyword',
@Col4 tinyint = 162,
@Col3 varchar(255) = 'value';

;WITH Entity_CTE (EntityId, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4,LastUpdated, Details2, Details1)  
AS  
(  
    SELECT 
        Entity.[EntityId], 
        Entity.[Col1],
        Entity.[Col2], 
        Entity.[Col3], 
        Entity.[Col4],
        Entity.[LastUpdated],
        EntityDetails.[Details2],
        EntityDetails.[Details1]
    FROM [Entity] WITH (NOLOCK) 
        INNER JOIN [EntityDetails] WITH (NOLOCK) on Entity.[EntityId] = EntityDetails.[EntityId] 
    WHERE 
        CONTAINS((EntityDetails.[Details1],EntityDetails.[Details2]), @Keywords) 
        AND 
        Entity.[Col4]=@Col4 
        AND CONTAINS((Entity.[Col3]), @Col3)  
)  
SELECT EntityId, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Details2, Details1  
FROM Entity_CTE
ORDER BY [LastUpdated] DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY;
```

**I have below IO statistics:**

```
Table 'EntityDetails'. Scan count 0, logical reads 4299, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 22, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Entity'. Scan count 1, logical reads 22, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
```

**When using above query inside a stored procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_TEMP
@Keywords varchar(255),
@Col4 tinyint = 162,
@Col3 varchar(255)

AS

;WITH Entity_CTE (EntityId, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4,LastUpdated, Details2, Details1)  
AS  
(  
    SELECT 
        Entity.[EntityId], 
        Entity.[Col1],
        Entity.[Col2], 
        Entity.[Col3], 
        Entity.[Col4],
        Entity.[LastUpdated],
        EntityDetails.[Details2],
        EntityDetails.[Details1]
    FROM [Entity] WITH (NOLOCK) 
        INNER JOIN [EntityDetails] WITH (NOLOCK) on Entity.[EntityId] = EntityDetails.[EntityId] 
    WHERE 
        CONTAINS((EntityDetails.[Details1],EntityDetails.[Details2]), @Keywords) 
        AND 
        Entity.[Col4]=@Col4 
        AND CONTAINS((Entity.[Col3]), @Col3)  
)  
SELECT EntityId, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Details2, Details1  
FROM Entity_CTE
ORDER BY [LastUpdated] DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY;
```

**I see below IO statistics:**

```
Table 'EntityDetails'. Scan count 0, logical reads 180, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 1401, logical reads 65571, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Entity'. Scan count 1, logical reads 22, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
```

**Update 4**

It seems that using `OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 4136)` fixes the issue, but I am not sure about possible implications, does it has any negative impact?

Comment: Hi, Naveed Ahmed.
Please, we'll be able to better help you if your performance question contained the execution plan and query being executed, like [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/259780/creating-an-index-that-is-not-used-by-a-select-query-reduces-performance-of-th).

Comment: Thank you so much Ronaldo for your reply, I have added the query plan to the question, can you please take a look.

Comment: Is there a performance problem or you just want to avoid a worktable in your exec plan?

Comment: The query performance is poor (runs slow) when I apply ORDER BY LastUpdated DESC. And I want the results to be sorted by last modified date. If I make ORDER BY EntityId the results are returned very quickly, I want the same performance but with LastUpdated DESC.Is it possible? I think the performance problem is due to the worktable/ Index Spool(Eager)

Comment: Could you also run the query without the `ORDER BY` using the same parameters and add that query plan so that we can compare them?

Comment: Here you go https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyelYg99I

Comment: It's possible that using the index `IX_EntityLastUpdated` is the problem. The best use of an index is when a predicate references the index key in a JOIN condition or WHERE clause, but your query has no predicate on  the column `LastUpdated` that is the key of that index. But by adding the `ORDER BY Entity.[LastUpdated] DESC` I think you made SQL Server think that index would be the best choice for the query. Let's try to force it not to use that index and see if that makes sence.

Comment: To do that try runing the query with bad performance substituting the `FROM` you have for this: `FROM 
 [Entity] WITH (NOLOCK, INDEX(PK_Entity)) 
 INNER JOIN [EntityDetails] WITH (NOLOCK) on Entity.[EntityId] = EntityDetails.[EntityId]` and see if it generates the same execution plan of the query with good performance.

Comment: I have updated the post with the updated plans, can you please take a look?

Comment: definitely not the result I was expecting. But since the query hint spoiled the plan of the `ORDER BY EntityId DESC` when it should not change, I think it wasn't the best way to avoid the use of the index `IX_EntityLastUpdated`. Was that index created for this specifc query we're trying to tune? if yes, could you [disable it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/disable-indexes-and-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15) and run your original query? (if it's production environment and you're not sure if it's used by other queries, **don't disable** the index).

Comment: I also rewrote the query and I'm gonna have to post as an answer because it doesn't fit on  this comment space, but it's a guess and I'm out of ideas for now. @LowlyDBA, any insight based on the new inputs of the question?

Comment: Yes I added this index for this specific query, because if you look at this plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkU6bEj5I you will notice the sort operation which I wanted to avoid and there was a clustered index scan which was returning millions of rows.