# Merge join asks for seemingly unnecessary sort before joining

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, performance-tuning, microsoft-dynamics

I use one table to update another table. Both the tables have a clustered index where the first 4 columns are the same type of data.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [i109139_I_109139CLI_44C9176D64C84ECB959C0EAA6AE7A4F4] ON [dbo].[t109139_44C9176D64C84ECB959C0EAA6AE7A4F4]
(
    [PARTITION] ASC,
    [DATAAREAID] ASC,
    [ITEMID] ASC,
    [INVENTSERIALID] ASC,
    [RECID] ASC
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[INVENTSERIAL] ADD  CONSTRAINT [I_1204ITEMSERIALIDX] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PARTITION] ASC,
    [DATAAREAID] ASC,
    [ITEMID] ASC,
    [INVENTSERIALID] ASC
)
```

The following is the query I use to update the tables

```
UPDATE T1
    SET NOTFORPROJECTS = T2.LANNOTFORPROJECTS
FROM tempdb."DBO".t109139_44C9176D64C84ECB959C0EAA6AE7A4F4 T1
CROSS JOIN LANINVENTSERIALVIEW T2
WHERE T1.PARTITION = 5637144576
  AND T1.DATAAREAID = N'lan'
  AND T2.PARTITION = 5637144576
  AND T2.DATAAREAID = N'lan'
  AND T2.INVENTSERIALID = T1.INVENTSERIALID
  AND T2.ITEMID = T1.ITEMID
  AND T2.DATAAREAID = T1.DATAAREAID
  AND T2.PARTITION = T1.PARTITION
```

When I look at the queryplan, I notice that it does use the clustered indexes of both the tables, but it performs a hash match instead of a merge join. I find this unexpected as the used data should both be sorted on the equality operators.

So then I try to force a Merge join, and it seems that SQL Server still uses both the clustered indexes, but first sorts the data from the two tables from ItemId,InventSerialId to InventSerialId,ItemId and then uses that to perform a merge join. So it basically swaps the two columns.

Do note that in the table InventSerial, only 1 InventSerialId is an empty string, and in the other table that I update, there will be many empty-string (not null) InventSerialIds. I have no idea if this is relevant.

Query plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1L4j7EF3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can repro this too ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/j_XKdern)).

If you change

```
  AND T2.INVENTSERIALID = T1.INVENTSERIALID
  AND T2.ITEMID = T1.ITEMID
```

To

```
  AND T2.ITEMID = T1.ITEMID  
  AND T2.INVENTSERIALID = T1.INVENTSERIALID
```

It is able to produce the desired plan (no sort operators in the final query in the Fiddle).

Somewhat unsatisfying that you have to do this but previously with `MERGE` join and `MERGE` union I have also found that tweaks are needed to get the hoped for plan ([example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/259780/creating-an-index-that-is-not-used-by-a-select-query-reduces-performance-of-th/259853#259853)).

Paul White previously commented on the above example

> Finding optimal ordering is NP-hard so database engines rely on
> heuristics.

Comment: You are correct, switching those two up, results in performing a Merge join, thanks a lot. I assumed the compiler would have resolved this for me.

Comment: The compiler will assume you had some other reason for the inconsistent ordering.  Anyway, dynamically changing the column order in an index, especially Clustered, is a major undertaking.

Comment: @RickJames - this is purely about changing the order that the predicates appear in the query text. Not about changing any index order

Answer (score 0):

The way you've posted the query and the query available in the plan are very different. It's the paranthesis. By putting those around the join criteria, you're forcing a logical order on the optimizer for which things can go first. Because of this, the optimizer doesn't see a way to use ordered data. That means either a hash join, or, when you force the merge join, sort operations.

This is from the plan:

> UPDATE T1  SET NOTFORPROJECTS=T2.LANNOTFORPROJECTS FROM
> tempdb."DBO".t109139_44C9176D64C84ECB959C0EAA6AE7A4F4 T1 CROSS  JOIN
> LANINVENTSERIALVIEW T2  WHERE ((T1.PARTITION=5637144576)   AND
> (T1.DATAAREAID=N'lan'))   AND (((T2.PARTITION=5637144576)   AND
> (T2.DATAAREAID=N'lan'))   AND ((((T2.INVENTSERIALID=T1.INVENTSERIALID)
> AND (T2.ITEMID=T1.ITEMID))   AND (T2.DATAAREAID=T1.DATAAREAID))   AND
> (T2.PARTITION=T1.PARTITION)))

Comment: The issue is reproducible with no parentheses in sight https://dbfiddle.uk/16BBJmiG

Comment: This is incorrect, the parentheses did not change anything. What happened is that I realized that I had used the generated T-SQL code and afterwards cleaned it up for better readability here.

Comment: Happy to get it wrong too.